# Trouble with SQL CTE

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, google-cloud-sql

Was writing a sql statment and the CTE query works but when wrapped it is giving me a syntax error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dateCTE (id, firstDate) AS (
select id, min(date' at line 1*

```
With dateCTE (id, firstDate) AS (
select id, min(date)
from notes
where deletion_time is null
and signed_time is not null
group by 1)

select *
from dateCTE;
```

Shoot sorry the where clause was part of it, I just missed it while copying it to stackoverflow.

Comment: Where did you define `dateCTE`?

Comment: @nicoHaase what do you mean define dateCTE... is that not what the "with dateCTE(....)" does.

Comment: Sorry for confusing - I had better asked the other way around: what do you want to do with `dateCTE`? Shouldn't there be anything to be selected from that?

Comment: yea this was part of a larger query but when debugging with a simple ```select *
from dateCTE;``` I got the syntax error

Comment: ....then please share the **exact** query that triggers your problem. In the given example, there is no `from dateCTE`

Comment: I added the from dateCTE part.

Answer (score 1):

We are running 5.7 not 8 and this is just not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need `cte`, only single `select` statement would help you :

```
select id, min(date)
from notes
where deletion_time is null and signed_time is not null
group by id;
```

Note : You need where clause to filter the `null`s & calls to `cte immediate after declaration :

```
With dateCTE (id, firstDate) AS (
      select id, min(date)
      from notes
      where deletion_time is null and signed_time is not null
      group by id
    )
select *
from dataCTE;
```

Comment: thanks, this is part of a larger query and I was attempting to debug this section as it throws the syntax error ... it is also the first CTE that is defined.... i updated as I did have the where just forgot to copy to StackOverflow also was using a similar statement ```select *
from dateCTE;```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.  You are missing a `where` in the CTE.  And you are missing a `select`.  So:

```
With dateCTE (id, firstDate) AS (
      select id, min(date)
      from notes
      where deletion_time is null and signed_time is not null
      group by 1
    )
select *
from dataCTE;
```

Note:  This assumes that your database supports `group by 1`.

Comment: yea sorry that was a fat finger mistake... i edited to reflect the where. Also I tested the query without the CTE wrapper and it worked so assuming that group by 1 is supported.